# How to retrieve a LastPass auto-generated password?

Tags: lastpass

I used LastPass to register a Gmail account. I need the password to enter it into Mail.app, Apple's email client, but I don't know the password. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very easy to find out.

You need to go to http://www.lastpass.com and sign in. Once signed in you will be shown your "LastPass Vault". In the list of passwords their will be your GMail account. Click the edit link.

Next to the password box, click `Show`. It will then display your password in clear text.

<sub>Note: If you have the LastPass browser extension installed, you can access your vault using this rather than browsing to the LastPass website. Either way will work</sub>

Answer (score 30):

If you just generated it, but for some reason not stored as a site in Lastpass after you registered with the site, there is a way to retrieve it, if you used the browser extension.

Click on the Lastpass button in your browser, go to "Generate Secure Password", click the dropdown button on the password field. Hopefully the top entry should be your latest generated password. Select it and click "copy password".

This just happened to me on a site with a non quite standard sign up process, e.g. there was no confirm password field, so no entry for it was ever added to Lastpass.

Comment: Did they recently remove this option?  I don't see it anymore.

Comment: This worked in my case, had created a password for a brand new site registration that never saved. Also noticed that when I left the site (navigated to another site on same tab) LastPass detected that I had not saved it and was prompted this time around.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext it looks like the UI has been updated to explicitly show history. See my answer below.

Comment: You saved the day, thanks :")

Answer (score 15):

You can now look at the history of your generated passwords using the browser extension. Just click the extension icon then choose `Generate Secure Password` > `Show History`.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now, if you know the general time you generated the password, it's quite easy to recover the password.

Comment: How often does this history clear? I went looking for one generated a few days ago there, but my list was empty.

Comment: @CivFan annoyingly, it seems to be daily.

Comment: looks like they've removed the ability to look at generated password history entirely?

Answer (score 3):

In case you accidentally overwrote the generated password (happened to me) - you can still retrieve it by doing the following:

1. Login to lastpass
2. Find the account for which you need to retrieve the password
3. Edit the account - may need to right-click account icon to find edit option
4. Look for the clock above the password dialog
5. Clicking the clock reveals a history of passwords for that account